# Add Part object to observableArrayList<Part> associatedParts in the Product class in Java

Tags: java

I am working on my class assignment and I am stuck.

I have two classes: Part, which is abstract and has InHouse and Outsourced classes that extend Part. Then I have Product, which oddly has an observableArrayList of parts called associatedParts.

I am working on my AddProductController, trying to make a call to the method in the `Product` class `addAssociatedPart()`. My problem is the compiler doesn't find the method in Part. If I cast to an InHouse, it doesn't find the method in InHouse, and so on. I can't use a static method, because the method `addAssociatedPart()` is supposed to be non-static per the UML design. So, I can't tell it explicitly to find it in `Product.addAssociatedPart()`, because it tells me I can't reference a non-static etc.

Here's the code snippets starting with the Product class.

```
public class Product {
private ObservableList<Part> associatedParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private int id;
private String name;
private double price;
private int stock;
private int min;
private int max;

public void addAssociatedPart(Part part) {

   getAllAssociatedParts().add(part);
}

public ObservableList<Part> getAllAssociatedParts() {
    return this.associatedParts;
}
```

And then the AddProductScreenController class:

```
public class AddProductScreenController implements Initializable {

@FXML
public void onAddProductAddPart(ActionEvent event) {

    // this is triggered when the Add button is clicked

    Part selectedItem = addProductTableViewAll.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    selectedItem.addAssociatedPart(); // can't find method
    Product.selectedItem.addAssociatedPart(); // can't find variable selectedItem (obviously bad formatting)
    selectedItem.Product.addAssociatedPart(); // can't find variable Product (again bad formatting)
    addAssociatedPart(selectedItem); // can't find method addAssociatedPart()
    Product.addAssociatedPart(selectedItem); // non-static method, can't be referenced from a static context

    InHouse newPart = new InHouse(1, "test", 1.99, 1, 1, 1, 101);
    addAssociatedPart(newPart); // can't find method
    Product.addAssociatedPart(newPart); // non-static method
    newPart.addAssociatedPart(); // can't find method


    addProductTableViewPartial.setItems(associatedParts);
}
}
```

The part code as requested:

```
public abstract class Part {
private int id;
private String name;
private double price;
private int stock;
private int min;
private int max;


public ObservableList<Part> allParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public Part(int id, String name, double price, int stock, int min, int max) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.stock = stock;
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return this.price;
}

public void setStock(int stock) {
    this.stock = stock;
}
public int getStock() {
    return this.stock;
}

public void setMin(int min) {
    this.min = min;
}
public int getMin() {
    return this.min;
}

public void setMax(int max) {
    this.max = max;
}
public int getMax() {
    return this.max;
}

}
```

This is InHouse

```
 package model;



public class InHouse extends Part {
    private int machineId;

    public InHouse(int id, String name, double price, int stock, int min, int max, int machineId) {
        super(id, name, price, stock, min, max);
        this.machineId = machineId;
    }



    public void setMachineId(int machineId) {
        this.machineId = machineId;
    }
    public int getMachineId() {
        return this.machineId;
    }

}
```

And then Outsourced:

```
    package model;


public class Outsourced extends Part {

    private String companyName;

    public Outsourced(int id, String name, double price, int stock, int min, int max, String companyName) {

        super(id, name, price, stock, min, max);
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return this.companyName;
    }
}
```

If there is a particular part of Java you feel I need to brush up on to understand this, I am wide open to that. I want to understand the issue, not just get a fix. I'm not even looking for the answer, just a point in the direction of what the problem is.

### Update

@Le and @Jackson pointed me in the right direction with their comments on the response he provided. I need to have a product first:

```
Product product = new Product(1, "test", 1.99, 1, 1, 1);
product.addAssociatedPart(selectedItem);
```

Comment: Could you please show us the Part code?

Comment: @NomadMaker just added Part and the extensions of Part.

Comment: If it is not a static method, you must attach it to an object.

Comment: Why are you calling `newPart.addAssociatedPart();`? `newPart` is of type `Part` which does not have instance method `addAssociatedPart()`

Comment: From architecture point of view, (I am assuming) `Product` is composed of one or many `Part`s. So adding part to a product is a behavior for product. In Java world, that behavior is translated to methods. Which is what your `Product` class has `addAssociatedPart()`

Comment: Because I need to add the part as an associatedpart to the product. The UML design has the method in the Product class and Product also has a private variable Observable list named associatedParts.

Comment: @nabster you are right, Product is made up of at least one Part

Comment: Right, but why this `newPart.addAssociatedPart();`? Where `newPart` is-of type `InHouse` which in return is-a `Part`. Unless there's a method on `Part` say `addMeToProduct(Product hostProduct)`.

Comment: I tried the cast as well and same result. It doesn't matter if I cast as InHouse or Outsourced or just try .addAssociatedParr(). I am new to Java so it's the only way I know to call a nonstatic method. Otherwise I don't know how I will add the part to the product because there is no method in part to support this per the uml

Comment: Possible to share UML diagram? People would be likely to help you through this inheritance problem if they can see the objects hierarchy.

Comment: Could you please paste the exact text of the compiler error into your question?

Comment: getAllAssociatedParts() looks like it should be a member of the Product class, and I'm confused as to why you think it should be part of something else.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to get the UML attached...it's in a pdf format

Comment: Okay, @Jackson helped me understand what I was missing, and my apologies for being dense and not understanding all of your questions. The end result is I have to have the Product object first, make the method call from the product, and send the part as the argument. so Product newProduct = new Product(data entered...); product.addAssociatedPart(selectedItem); works Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I was trying to explain you association of your various classes in comments but thought I would use visual help. I have simplified your scenario into a classic OOP problem.

```
public class Product {

    public void addAssociatedPart(Part part) {
        // some stuff
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class Part {
}
```

```
public class InHouse extends Part {
}
```

```
public class Outsourced extends Part {
}
```

```
public class Assembly {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product car = new Product();

        Part seat = new InHouse();
        Part engine = new Outsourced();
        Part window = new InHouse();

        car.addAssociatedPart(seat);
        car.addAssociatedPart(engine);
        car.addAssociatedPart(window);
    }
}
```

I do not have any method in my `Part` or its sub-classes to add themselves to some `Product`. Was this you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes! Man I can't believe I wasted 7 hours on this! Literally I've been stuck on this all day and couldn't see that I need to make the product object first. I appreciate all the help. I want to dig in my book to get a better understanding so I don't miss this in the future.

Comment: Glad we could help! SO community has taught us a lot and I am always there to give back.

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on my AddProductController, trying to make a call to the
>   method in the Product class addAssociatedPart().
>
> My problem is the compiler doesn't find the method in Part.

Why should it? Is Part a child of Product? Otherwise, you are calling a Product Method using a Part instance.

To use the methods of Inhouse and Oursourced for parts, you can do something like this

```
if (selectedItem instanceof InHouse){
    Inhouse inhouse = (Inhouse)selectedItem;
    //do what you need with inhouse methods
}else{
   Outsourced outsourced = (Outsourced)selectedItem;
   //do what you need with oursourced method
}
```

Comment: I have to be able to call the method addAssociatedPart() in the Product class. That's per the UML design for my class, so I don't get a choice in that. I tried casting as you point out, and when I get down to the result, I still cannot access the addAssociatedPart() method.

Comment: You just need to create the object to use it: Product product = new Product();
        product.addAssociatedPart(selectedItem );

Comment: @KeithG Perhaps post your UML here then. Unless Part is a child of Product there is no reason why Part should be able to call the Product Methods. Of course unless Part itself has the method addAssociatedPart()

Comment: Okay, I think that makes sense, @Jackson. I will try adding a Product object and sending it that way.

Comment: That fixed it! I had to first have a Product created and then call the method from that Product object. @FXML
    public void onAddProductAddPart(ActionEvent event) {
        
        // this is triggered when the Add button is clicked
        
        Part selectedItem = addProductTableViewAll.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        
        Product product = new Product(1, "test", 1.99, 1, 1, 1);
        product.addAssociatedPart(selectedItem);
        
        
        addProductTableViewPartial.setItems(associatedParts);
    }

Comment: @LêHoàngDững you are right, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are confused with static and non static method. You need a Product instance to access AddAssociatedPart(). Visualize your class in class diagram.

[image]

```
public void onAddProductAddPart(ActionEvent event) {

// this is triggered when the Add button is clicked

Part selectedItem = addProductTableViewAll.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
selectedItem.addAssociatedPart(); // addAssociatedPart() is method of Product, not Part
Product.selectedItem.addAssociatedPart(); // Product class has no static member selectedItem   
selectedItem.Product.addAssociatedPart(); // syntax error
addAssociatedPart(selectedItem); // addAssociatedPart() is not method of AddProcutController
Product.addAssociatedPart(selectedItem); // if you reference the method start with a class, the method is expected to be a static method. addAssociatedPart() is not a static method, call it with a product instance

InHouse newPart = new InHouse(1, "test", 1.99, 1, 1, 1, 101);
addAssociatedPart(newPart); // addAssociatedPart() is not part of AddProductController
Product.addAssociatedPart(newPart); // dont reference non-static method with a class name
newPart.addAssociatedPart(); // addAssociatedPart() is not part of Part


addProductTableViewPartial.setItems(associatedParts);
}
```